# CopyOnWriteArraySet

Tags: многопоточность, java

Здравствуйте. Есть сет, куда в несколько потоков добавляются числа. Каждые десять секунд мне надо сделать некие действия со всеми элементами этого сета, а затем очистить его. Сейчас у меня это происходит вот таким образом, но я так понимаю, что set.clear() удаляет и то, что было добавлено в сет после цикла с выборкой. Это так? И, если да, как этого избежать?

```
Set<Integer> set = new CopyOnWriteArraySet<Integer>();
//в сет постоянно добавляются значения из других потоков

while (true) {
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    Iterator<Integer> it = set.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Integer a=it.next();
        //некие действия с полученным числом
    }
    set.clear();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно же Set будет полностью очищен при вызове метода `clear`. Кроме того, коллекция`CopyOnWriteArraySet` - не лучший выбор, если вы постоянно добавляете/удаляете элементы, т.к. на каждую модификацию создается новая копия множества. Данная реализация хорошо подходит при частых чтениях и редких модификациях.

В вашем случае лучше использовать обычное множество, например `HashSet`, доступ к которому на добавление синхронизирован. Каждый раз, когда вам нужно обработать элементы множества, вы можете в критической секции заменить ссылку на пустое множество, в которое будут продолжать добавляться элементы, а элементы из предыдущего множества обработать и удалить.

Comment: @a_gura,спасибо за ответ. А как заменить ссылку? Мне приходит в голову только создать новый класс, который будет содержать в себе 2 сета, и метод, который будет возвращать ссылку на один или второй, в зависимости от ситуации.

Comment: @Dazar
  Set processingSet = set;
  set = new HashSet();

Теперь в `set` добавляются новые элементы, а элементы из `processingSet` можно обрабатывать.

Comment: @a_gura, спасибо. Я это решение весь вечер искал, так и не додумался сам.